# You could help me, couldn't you?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, geometry

### Introduction

> I am an enthusiastic geometry student, preparing for my first quiz. Yet while revising I accidentally spilt my coffee onto my notes. Can you rescue me and draw me a diagram so that I can revise it for tomorrow’s test? Thank you very much!

### My Notes

> [image]

Comment: You seem to forget a lot ;). Anyway - all part of your friendly neighborhood moderator’s service hehe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> These images represent the first three Propositions of Euclid's Elements. So the fourth one represents Proposition 4 (side-angle-side triangle congruence). Here's your diagram:[image]